# iPhone - Certificate Signing Request not showing in Distribution Profile

Tags: iphone, certificate, distribution, csr

We're trying to get our app ready for distribution on the app store. We provisioned it for a single device which works well so we know its not the code. We create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) and upload it as instructed (we followed lots of videos and done a lot of reading) but when we hit submit to upload our CSR the page seems to refresh and the certificate doesn't appear in the Distribution tab of the Provisioning Portal.

Is there a stage we've missed beforehand or is this a common problem?
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is still active, or if you still need help but I had the same problem and I found the solution.

Use safari.

I was using chrome, and it won't work outside safari apparently.